# How to use google pay on expo

Tags: react-native, expo, stripe-payments, payment

I'm working on a project, which requires payment with google . expo project init on managed workflow and i have Priority plan on expo for EAS build ,

[I'm used this link for integrate payment with expo](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/stripe/)

I did the initial setup according to the documentation .
But I do not know how to use google pay in the expo application

Nowhere in this documentation about integrate with Google pay

**Anyone have any information about this, please tell me in the answers section**

Answer (score 2):

You should refer to this section to use Google Pay: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/stripe/#google-pay.

To test it out, use your test mode API keys (both publishable and secret key), add a valid Google Pay card to your device and run with the steps above. It will create a test 4242 card (instead of your real card) and create a test mode only Charge.

Comment: yah , I see it , but i'm not sure this is true way for integrate google pay with stripe .  Do you have a sample code implemented to pay with Google?

Comment: I do not have sample code but that is the documented way to test out Google Pay using your Expo app, why do you think it is not the right way?